# Change color of a input value represented as text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I created a interest calculator and i want the money amount and interest to turn to color green and not the whole text string.

So far I've tried with different type of dom manipulations, but haven't been successful in singeling out these two values. `document.getElementById("resultat").style.color = "green";` will turn the whole text to green...

In my code i have the `var startAar` and the `var rente`, the two is as a input value and shown in a `textarea`.

How can i accomplish this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Rente Kalkulator</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/af4e45f5ea.js"></script>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon.ico">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload = btn;

  function btn() {
   document.getElementById("btn").onclick = regnUt; 
  }

  
  function regnUt() {
   var startAar = 1; // Start år er satt til 1
   var pengeBelop = document.getElementById("pengeBelop").value; // Bruker input i "Pengebeløp"
   var antallAar = document.getElementById("antallAar").value; // Bruker input i "Antall år"
   var rente = document.getElementById("rente").value; // Bruker input i "Rente"

   for (var antallAar; startAar <= antallAar; startAar++) { // Sjekk om brukers "Antall år" input er mindre en startAar, startAar = 1, legg til 1 til startAar samsvarer antallAar
    
    if (startAar < antallAar) { // Om startAar er mindre en antallAar, legg til startAar til pengeBelop
     pengeBelop += startAar;
    }

    pengeBelop = pengeBelop * (1+rente/100); // Formel for rente

    document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML += "Etter " + startAar + " år " + "har jeg " +  pengeBelop.toFixed(0) + "kr" + " om renten er på " + rente + "%" + ("\n");
    document.getElementById("resultat").style.border = " 2px solid #6dc066";
   }
  }
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  body {
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  h1 {
   padding-top: 3%;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   color: #f7f7f7;
   font-size: 35px;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
  }

  h1:hover {
   font-size: 38px;
  }

  a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #f7f7f7;
  }

  h3 {
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
   color: #333333;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 12%;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
   font-size: 24px;
  }

  #header {
   height: 25vh;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #6dc066;
   display: block;
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }

  #kalkulator {
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
   float: left;
   padding-left: 15%;
   margin-top: 15px;
  }

  #resultat {
   float: right;
   margin-top: 5%;
   margin-right: 7%;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-left: 70px;
   line-height: 25px;
   resize: none;
   text-align: left;
  }

  #resultat:focus {
   outline: none;
   border: 2px solid #6dc066;
  }

  input {
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-bottom: 12px;
   padding-right: 130px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 22px;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
  }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
  input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      margin: 0; 
  }

  input:focus {
   outline: none;
   border: 2px solid #6dc066;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
  }

  button {
   margin-top: 25px;
   padding: 15px 40px;
   border-style: none;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   border-radius: 8px;
   color: white;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: #6dc066;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  button:hover {
   padding: 17px 70px;
   font-size: 18px;
   background-color: #333333;
   color: #f7f7f7;
  }

  button:focus {
   outline: none;
  }

  button:active {
   background-color: #333333;
   box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
   transform: translateY(8px);
  }
  
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1><a href="ekstra1.html">Rentekalkulator</a><br/><i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
</div>
<div id="kalkulator">
<h3>Pengebeløp:</h3>
<input type="number" id="pengeBelop" placeholder="kr"><br/> 
<h3>Antall år:</h3>
<input type="number" id="antallAar" placeholder="år"><br/>
<h3>Rente:</h3>
<input type="number" id="rente" placeholder="%"><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn">Regn ut</button><br/>
</div>
<textarea readonly cols='55' rows='15' id="resultat"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: You can not just change part of the string in an text input / textarea.

Comment: You need to put the value you want to change color into a separate element , such as a span and then target that with CSS to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear , but i sugguest you to add this to the end of your style tag  (I mean after **button:active** selectpr):

```
input[type='text'], input[type='number'],textarea{
            color: green;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not style individual words within a `textarea` element, the style is applied to **all** of the text in the textarea.

If the `resultat` element is only for displaying a message to the user and **not** for inputting values, then perhaps you can replace it with a `div` element and inside that `div` wrap the text-parts that you want to highlight with `span` elements:

The HTML: `<div id="resultat"></div>`, set height and width in CSS.

The javascript:

```
document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = 
    "Etter "+"<span class='startAar'>"+startAar+" år "+"</span>"+
    "har jeg "+"<span class='belop'>"+pengeBelop.toFixed(0)+"kr"+"</span>"+
    "om renten er på "+"<span class='rente'>"+rente+"%"+"</span>"+
   ("\n");
```

The CSS:

```
.startAar, .belop, .rente {
    color: green;
}

#resultat {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```